# Power management problems

Tags: 16.04

My laptop Asus X453SA and installed ubuntu 16.04

Ubuntu can not detect charge. however charge worked well. in applet and power management all experiencing the same problem. This does not occur in Windows . I was tried reinstall ubuntu but always same .

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem, first charge you laptop to 100% and install power calibrate from Terminal using the below command:

`sudo apt-get install power-calibrate`

Once Power Calibrate is installed and your laptop is fully charged unplug the power cable and run Power Calibrate from the terminal using the below command:

`sudo power-calibrate`

Run this in the background and let you battery fully discharge and that will fix your problem.

Comment: I was try and not work